# How does a VPC protect microservices behind an API gateway?

Tags: microservices

I could use some advice… I think I might be missing something obvious here but I’m trying to understand how microservices communicate when using the API gateway or BFF networking pattern. Each of the microservices will obviously have an API as well, so how are they any less accessible than the API gateway? Surely they have HTTP endpoints as well? How does a virtual network limit the microservices to only being accessible from the API gateway? Does that make sense? All the tutorials I find online seem to assume I understand! I’m confused.

Microservices network diagram

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Microservices in your VPC have private IP addresses that are only directly routable within that VPC.  They are not available on the internet at all, unless you explicitly provide them with a public IP, or via another way in, like an API gateway, load balancer with an assigned public IP, transit gateway, etc.

Resources in your VPC can also be assigned to security groups that provide fine control over which IP addresses are allowed to communicate with them on which ports.

Comment: Should microservices which are only connected through a VPC still use any form of authentication, like OAuth Client Credentials Flow?